AWT tray icon gets inresponsive when taskbar is recreated? (Windows 10)
In my java application I'm using a tray icon with a small menu. I experienced issues on Windows when waking up the laptop from hibernation and I found out that this is happening in scenarios where the Windows task bar is recreated. I can also simulate this by restarting explorer.exe in taskmanager.
In these scenarios the tray icon becomes inresponsive, i.e. the menu is not shown anymore when right-clicking on the icon and the actionlistener when clicking on the icon is also not working anymore.
I managed to create a small demo-class that has the same behavior. It seems that the issue only appears when at least one notification was shown. It also seems that removing and re-adding the tray-icon after sending the notification (see out-commented code) solves this issue.
Minimum example:
import java.awt.MenuItem;
import java.awt.PopupMenu;
import java.awt.SystemTray;
import java.awt.TrayIcon;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class TrayIconDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        final SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
        final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();

        BufferedImage whiteImage = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
        whiteImage.setRGB(0, 0, 0xFFFFFF);
        final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(whiteImage, "tray icon");

        // Create a popup menu components
        MenuItem aboutItem = new MenuItem("About");
        aboutItem.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("about clicked"));
        popup.add(aboutItem);

        trayIcon.setPopupMenu(popup);
        trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
        trayIcon.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("tray clicked"));

        tray.add(trayIcon);

        trayIcon.displayMessage("hello world", "some text", java.awt.TrayIcon.MessageType.ERROR);
        //tray.remove(trayIcon);
        //tray.add(trayIcon);
    }
}

Am I doing something wrong with the way I display tray icon messages (notifications?), does it need to be invoked from a specific thread? Or is there a bug in AWT or the Windows API?
Thanks in advance! =)
Software used on the laptop:

Windows 10 Enterprise (x86_64)
Java 17 runtime (Azul Zulu 17.0.10)


Also added a gif recording to showcase it: https://ibb.co/CzY5GPz

A workaround for this might be passing your own implementation of SystemSleepListener to Desktop.getDesktop().addAppEventListener.

Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately it's not called when I do hibernation on my laptop.  Only is UserSessionListener called afterwards since I have to re-login when the system waked up. The other issue is that the tray icon recreation can happen also when the system crashes or when the Screen resolution changes or additional screens are attached I guess. My workaround right now is to have a MouseListener that checks if the ActionListener is called afterwards. For some reason the MouseListeners continue to work.

Of course this is also kind of ugly and it would be better to listen for the Windows TaskbarCreated event which would involve the use of JNA. For now I decided against this since I didn't want to use the net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform library which is quite big. An alternative would be to build a custom dll file with C/C++ that just listens for this "TaskbarCreated" Windows message.

If you’re willing to use Java 22, the java.lang.foreign package is part of Java SE and can invoke native C functions.  I’ve used it, it works quite well.
